# Radio button tab focus is not working properly after select any one radio button 

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem with tab focus using radio button after select any one of them. 
please check this eg. http://jsfiddle.net/muthukumar0705/yGeGr/7/

before selecting any radio button place the cursor on first textbox in eg and click tab. 
Tab focus is working fine is move textbox,radio button,textbox radio button.. but when i selected any one of the radio button. the tab focus will is not like above.

what i need is the tab focus alway move like textbox,radio button,textbox,radio button... when i  select radio button or not. How should i do this?

Comment: What does this question have to do with JavaScript, jQuery, or HTML5?

Comment: there is any possible to control with onblur or focus() like that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard Focus Breaking with Radio Button Group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155991/keyboard-focus-breaking-with-radio-button-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use tab index

```
tabindex="1"
tabindex="2"
etc...
```

[W3C link for tabindex](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.11.1)

Comment: i try this but not working after select the radio button http://jsfiddle.net/muthukumar0705/mDKtX/

Comment: Its working as expected, the radio buttons you have are all part of the same group, if you want them to focus separately they will need not to be in the same group.

Comment: thanks for your reply matthew. i know is radio button not from same group means is working fine. There is any possible to get the tab focus with same group name.

Comment: Sorry, no, not without some serious (and dubious) JavaScript blur actions, there is a thread here that echoes this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155991/keyboard-focus-breaking-with-radio-button-group